# pre-typedef'ing a variadic-function-pointer argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, variadic

I have a function `foo` that takes a variadic function pointer as its argument.

I would like to use "using" to define the argument's type prior to the function declaration.

```
template <typename ... vARGS>
using TFuncType = void(*)(vARGS ... V_args);

template <typename ... vARGS>
void foo(TFuncType<vARGS ...> funcptr) {}

void bar(int i) {}

int main() {
  foo(&bar); // This line fails to compile.
}
```

This doesn't compile. The error (via clang using c++1z) is:

```
/make/proj/test/variadic-funcparam-deduce2.cpp:39:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
foo(&bar);
^~~
/make/proj/test/variadic-funcparam-deduce2.cpp:33:36: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with vARGS = int]
template <typename ... vARGS> void foo(TFuncType<vARGS ...> funcptr) {}
```

Why is the "int" substitution failing?

I can successfully compile if I explicitly write the type inside foo():

```
template <typename ... vARGS>
void foo(void(*funcptr)(vARGS ... V_args)) {}
```

But I cannot get the initial ("using") version to work even when explicitly specifying the template parameters, and using a pre-casted `TFuncType<int>` for the argument, i.e.:

```
int main() {
  TF_call<int> fptr = &bar; // This line is OK.
  foo<int>(fptr);
}
```

Does anyone know what's up here?

Is there something strange about using typedef'd ("using") variadics and/or function pointers that I'm missing?

Comment: Works with GCC, and I can't think of any rule this code breaks, so I'm going to go with a Clang bug.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it for an hour or so then file a bug report if no further comments. Thanks.

Comment: I sent this through clang 3.6 via -std=c++14 without issue. Fyi, Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)

Comment: Just doing a trunk update now so I can retest before reporting. I think it was around 2 months old, but a bit hard to check at the moment. I believe it was with 3.7.0, via trunk.

Comment: For me: fails with clang release 3.4, 3.5, 3.6; works with gcc 4.7, 4.8, 4.9. Looks legal to me, too.

Comment: also fails with trunk 241397 (3.7.0, a few hours ago). will submit bug.

Comment: Ok, I submitted bug, but I got to wondering: Is this the same issue as my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945432/c-correct-syntax-for-friending-a-template-type-member-of-template-parameter). Basically, is the compiler not _supposed_ to do reverse lookups on variadic typedefs. Maybe GCC's accepting invalid.

Comment: This is definitely a Clang bug; a debug build of Clang asserts on this code.

Comment: I have a bug report here: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24032. However, I'm waiting on responses. I'm unconvinced that it's clang getting it wrong, rather than GCC wrongly accepting it. An earlier question I posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945432) has a related issue with reverse-lookups on variadic typedefs.

Comment: Interestingly enough, ICC 13 [rejects this code too](http://goo.gl/bg52PH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be related to the following text which I copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775296/459615) that itself takes from the C++ standard in 14.5.7 [temp.alias] paragraph 2:

> When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias template,
>   it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of
>   its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the type-id of
>   the alias template. **[ Note: An alias template name is never deduced. —
>   end note ]**

If I'm interpreting that right, it means that GCC accepting the code is actually non-conforming.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure now that it's illegal. Your snippet seems to explain it, thanks.

Comment: I'm not so sure. It says an alias template *name* is never deduced. It's not deducing the name, because the name is already given in the declaration of the template function. That caveat only seems to apply if your template expects a _template template_ parameter. See [the cppreference example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Alias_templates)